# Grid Responsive issue in @fluentui/react-northstar@0.49.0

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui

We are creating a Teams tab application and as suggested by Microsoft we are using @fluentui/react-northstar@0.49.0 for UI controls.
But there is no option for providing responsiveness in the Grid or pther layouts for making controls adjusting itslef based on the screen size (like different screen sizes, tablet and mobile).
Kindly let me know whether any option is available in that component or else we need to use any CSS framework outside for that purpose. Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grid https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/layout

The reason why you don't see screen sizes is because Grid uses flexbox, which is not the same as bootstrap grid system where it does show you screen sizes.

Not familiar why fluentui northstar exists but for web I'm using the Stack component as my grid system which also uses flexbox